# MySql 5.6 crashing on Ubuntu 15.04 arm64

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

At the end of the installation it throws error saying "Unable to set Root password".

I tried googling and reading other answers in stackoverflow for solutions but mysql always crashes while trying to start the mysql service using command

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

On examination of /var/log/mysql/error.log I find the following error

```
3ffa48ff1d0  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 4396512440784 in file fil0fil.cc line 5413
InnoDB: Failing assertion: node->n_pending > 0
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
03:40:01 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =    76297 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x44)[0x896dac]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150721 03:40:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

The complete log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/PvJQLg3B)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely [LP: #1427406](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1427406). A fix is available for 15.04 in the vivid-updates pocket, which is enabled by default on Ubuntu systems. Please try 'sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade'.